# Oracle SQL taking long time in second invocation

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am running a SQL query in Oracle 12.1.0 database, which is taking drastically different amount of time between first and subsequent invocations.

Our second and subsequent invocations are taking almost 10 times the time it took for first invocation.( too bad - that I don't have a cold backup ).

According to the developer, no changes have been made in the application or underlying tables.

We are truncating and analyzing (using DBMS_STATS) all relevant tables before each invocation. But are unable to replicate the performance seen in first invocation.

My gut feeling is that it has something to do with parsing and bad query plan.

The statement is as follows :

```
SELECT CASE input_val
      WHEN 'DEL'
      THEN
         (SELECT a_key
            FROM d_ad, ad_xr
           WHERE     d_ad.m_id = ad_xr.m_id
                 AND d_ad.source = ad_xr.source
                 AND ad_xr.c_id = :1
                 AND ad_xr.source = :3 )
      WHEN 'WRITE'
      THEN
         (SELECT w_key
            FROM wp_xr x, d_wl w
           WHERE     w.m_id = x.m_id
                 AND w.source = x.source
                 AND x.client_id = :4
                 AND x.source = :5 )
      WHEN 'APPEND'
      THEN
         (SELECT a_key
            FROM F0_A
           WHERE a_id = :5 AND source = :7 )
   END
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: I'm guessing - but are the second and subsequent invocations are running with different input values  for input_val?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan and determined that is doing something unexpected? I'm a little confused about when the first invocation was, if there's been time for potential code/table changes in between. You truncate and gather stats before each run; so the tables are empty when you run the query? Are you actually truncating or just deleting everything (which can cause issues with high water mark and full table scans)?You could also flush the shared pool to force a hard parse, and get the plan before and after; not sure if that will help here though.

Comment: Have the DBA's attempted a SGA Flush?  https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/oracle_rdbms_flushing_a_single  you may have a poor execution plan because stats changed so much.

Comment: @xQbert - We are rebooting the database server also before every invocation. Will that not flush the SGA ?

Comment: @Clay : the input_val are determined by an input data file, which is same for all invocations.

Comment: @oradbanj a reboot would flush SGA

Comment: First of all could you please attach the plan ?

Comment: @Alex Poole : We are actually truncating relevant tables. Also to clarify - we are not deleting from all tables. Regarding code/table changes - too bad we did not took a backup of the environment. So I have to rely upon whatever the developer says.

Comment: When you check the explain plan make sure to look at the "Notes" section.  I bet there are some adaptive query reoptimizations and the explain plan should mention it.

Comment: @agent5566 - I am trying to get the query plan.

Comment: @Jon Heller : I don't see any adaptive query reoptimizations. But in case subsequent invocations do - what are their downsides ?

Comment: So your 'first invocation' was some past time when everything was running fine but you don't have the execution plan; then you rebooted for some reason and had poor performance when you don't think anything else had changed; and since then you've been trying to restore performance by rebooting again and truncating and analysing the tables?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Correct. Our first invocation was about 15 days ago. The concerned person(s) did not took either backup or execution plan. None of us thought we will be in this situation. And now we are re-processing the batch file. The reason we are rebooting before each invocation is to ensure that caching does not becomes a factor. We are not expecting any breakthrough just by rebooting. I am kind of convinced that incorrect statistics and/or plan query plans are culprit here.

Comment: @agent5566 - the query plan exceeds limit of "Comment" box. Any alternative way of posting it ?

Comment: If you're lucky the old execution plan will be in AWR.  Try finding it like this:  `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr(sql_id => 'your_sql_id_here'));`.

Comment: You can put your plan on some listing sharing system for example https://gist.github.com/ or pastebin